# How do I write to a file from a function in terminal

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal

I want to write a function to my .bashrc file thats like:

```
function appendToFile {
  vi .file $1
}
```

and $1 is the contents. I know about the:

`program > path/to/file`

Format, but it's not a program, I want to just write a specific thing to a file.

Also, *important*, is that i dont want to overwrite the file, i want to append to the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "$1" >> file
```

could be your way. `>>` appends.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is multiline or needs to include variables, appendToFile should read from standard input:

```
#!/bin/bash
function appendToFile {
  cat >> "$1"
}

somevar="Hi, i'm some variable"

appendToFile ./test << EOF
multiline 1
multiline 2
$somevar
EOF

appendToFile ./test <<< "One line only"
```

Answer (score -2):

What about echo $1 > /path/to/file ?

Comment: Just checking, does that overwrite, or append?

Comment: -1: overwrites when the author specifically asked for `append`.